# Intermittent Foursquare API Response is 500

Tags: foursquare

I issue an authenticated call to `/venues/venue_id` but I get a `500` error

> "Foursquare servers are experiencing problems. Please retry and check
>   status.foursquare.com for updates."

I make about 60 of these calls, and only ~20 of them fail. It just started failing 3 days ago. Any ideas? What else do I need to provide?

Edit: The call I am making is:

> https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4ae2619bf964a520d58d21e3?oauth_token=xxxx&v=20120201

I make about 30 of these, and 10-12 work just fine, but the remaining fail. I tried the Foursquare API Explorer and I still get a 500 response.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about the kinds of calls you're making? 500s generally mean something is wrong on our end, but we definitely have not been serving 33% 500s over the last few days, so it's probably something unique about your request.

If you could paste the URLs you're hitting (without the OAuth token), it'd be helpful.

Comment: This is my call : https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4ae2619bf964a520d58d21e3?oauth_token=xxxx&v=20120201. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My API requests suddenly started working. No word why.